# How to control embedded text within this js script using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I dont have access to control the original script so i'm trying to style the text created for this scrolling text script using css and i'm not having any luck at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


scrollingTextSpeed = 75;
scrollingTextDirection = "Ticker";
scrollingTextx = 500;
scrollingTexty = 40 * 2;
scrollingTextxOffset = 6;
scrollingTextyOffset = 3;
var scrollingTextArray = new Array();
scrollingTextArray[0] = "Mock drafts available...";
scrollingTextArray[1] = "Link found in My League menu above...";
scrollingTextArray[2] = "Click on Find Mock Draft...";
scrollingTextArray[3] = "Winners prepare!";
;
scrollingTextIndex = 0;

function animateScrollingText () {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('scrollingText').getContext('2d');
   var displayText = scrollingTextArray[scrollingTextIndex];
   ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
   // ctx.fillStyle = document.body.style.color;
   ctx.font = "18" + "pt Verdana";
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,40);
   var dim = ctx.measureText(displayText);
   if (scrollingTextDirection == "Ticker") {
      scrollingTexty = 40/2;
      scrollingTextx -= scrollingTextxOffset;
      if (scrollingTextx < (dim.width * -1)) {
        scrollingTextx = 500;
         scrollingTextIndex++;
         if (scrollingTextIndex >= scrollingTextArray.length) {
            scrollingTextIndex = 0;
         }
      }
   } else {
     scrollingTextx = Math.round((500 - dim.width) / 2);
     scrollingTexty -= scrollingTextyOffset;
     if (scrollingTexty < 0) {
        scrollingTexty = 100;
         scrollingTextIndex++;
         if (scrollingTextIndex >= scrollingTextArray.length) {
            scrollingTextIndex = 0;
         }
     }
   }
   if (document.getElementById("scrollingTextLocation")) {
      document.getElementById("scrollingTextLocation").innerHTML = "scrollingTextx = " + scrollingTextx + ", scrollingTexty = " + scrollingTexty;
   }
   ctx.fillText(displayText,scrollingTextx,scrollingTexty);
}
</script>
```

And here is the html , i want to be able to contral the font color and size
I have tried #scrollingText {color:red!important} and canvas#scrollingText {color:red!important}

```
<div align="center">
<canvas id="scrollingText" width="500" height="40">
HTML5 Scrolling text goes here!
</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working using #scrollingText or canvas#scrollingText and even adding !important

Comment: wondering if its possible to add an over ride to this script and control the color with ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";  but i dont write js and wouldn't have a clue

Answer (score 2):

Your scrolling text isn't made of DOM elements. You can't control it at all using CSS.

The only control you have is using canvas' context functions and properties like the ones that are already used :

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.font = "18" + "pt Verdana";
```

To set the color to red, use

```
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
```

Comment: can i load up a separate script function to over ride the existing one to set the color and font size ? if so can you tell me what it would be , thanks

Comment: Yes, you can load a script almost identical, simply change the color as I showed. Load it after the first one has been loaded.

Comment: would i have to use it all, or a reduced version with only the color fillstyle listed?

Comment: You need everything. Did you already program in JavaScript or is that a first ?